# Is it useful to use After Effects when creating a Flash game?

Tags: flash, adobe, after-effects

Well, the title said everything, I saw some very nice effects using After Effects, but I want to apply those to a Flash game.. will it be useful?, or After Effects only works on cut scenes, animations, etc?

If you have some example, give me a link plz.

Thx.-

Answer (score 2):

It can be. You can intergrate video into Flash and apply After Affects to the video elements (of course that part is done outside of Flash first). This might interest you http://theflashblog.com/?p=1010